# How do I determine if connection pooling is working?

Tags: linux, windows-xp

Is there a reasonably simple way to measure (at the OS level) that connection pooling is working? I'm expecting to see a number of connections being established and staying that way. I suppose I'm only interested in tcp connection establishment/closing.

`netstat` only seems to give me the complete list. Surely there must be some tool that is more suitable for this task?

This is on Windows XP/Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [tcpview or Tcpvcon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx). Also you can run netstat -a -n -o | findstr YourProccessId in script that loops every second or so.